# Parcel won't stop emitting Source Maps even when sourceMaps is false in tsconfig.json

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, source-maps, parceljs, web-extension

I am building a Web Extension using ParcelJS v2.8.3 as the bundler and Parcel keeps emitting inline Source Maps even if tsconfig explicitly tells to not emit or to emit separately in .map.js files.

tsconfig.json

```
    "sourceMap": false,                                /* Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files. */
//"inlineSourceMap": false,                          /* Include sourcemap files inside the emitted JavaScript. */
//"inlineSources": false,                            /* Include source code in the sourcemaps inside the emitted JavaScript. */
```

background.js or any other file

```
"use strict"; # my code...
//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json....
```

If I set `sourceMap` option to true and `inlineSourceMap` and `inlineSources` to false (obviously uncommented) the result is the same above: Source Maps aren't emitted in .map.js neither exclude the source code.

I've already tried to exclude `.parcel-cache` folder and install the `@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc` but the problem continues.

.parcelrc

```
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-webextension",
  "transformers": {
    "*.{ts,tsx}": ["@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc"]
  }
}
```